# I cant understand why my TCP sever/clients are not working correctly

Tags: python-2.7

im building a chat server for personal use and im also building a client with it. I get an error after i input a string and send it to the server but i do not understand what it means or how to fix it. Could somebody assist?

Client code:

```
# chat_client.py
msg=""
import sys
import socket
import select

host="127.0.0.1"
port=9999

s=socket.socket()

s.connect((host,port))
while msg!="EXIT":
    msg=input("<You> ")
    s.send((str(msg)))
    print(s.recv(1024))
s.close
```

Server code:

```
import socket, subprocess
import threading

bind_ip="127.0.0.1"
bind_port= 9999

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server.bind((bind_ip,bind_port))
server.listen(5)

print("[*] Listening on %s:%d" % (bind_ip,bind_port))


def handle_client(client_socket):
    request = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print ("[*] Recieved: %s" %request)

    client_socket.send("ACK!")   
    client_socket.close()

while True:

    client,addr=server.accept()

    print("[*] Accepted Connection from %s:%d" % (addr[0],addr[1]))

    client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client(client,))
    client_handler.start()
```

Error msg:

```
<You> hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\python 2.7 socket stuff\TCP_CLIENT.py", line 14,
in <module>
    msg=input("<You> ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

The [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) function is dangerous because it will `eval()` the user's input which is not what you want. From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> **`input([prompt])`**
> Equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`.
>
> This function does not catch user errors. If the input is not syntactically valid, a `SyntaxError` will be raised. *Other exceptions may be raised if there is an error during evaluation.*
>
> Consider using the `raw_input()` function for general input from users.

Comment: it works and send the msg through to the server but when i send a second one i get [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Comment: That's a different error and a different question. But Stack Overflow isn't intended to hand-hold through the entire development / debug process. You need to learn debugging skills and use them.

Comment: ah i found the error, thanks for helping me out guys

Answer (score 0):

Python2's `input` tries to evaluate the inputted value. If you type `hello` it will search for a predefined `hello` variable.

You should use `raw_input` instead:

```
msg = raw_input("<You> ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 4444

int main(){

int clientSocket, ret;
struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
char buffer[1024];

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(clientSocket < 0){
    printf("[-]Error in connection.\n");
    exit(1);
}
printf("[+]Client Socket is created.\n");

memset(&serverAddr, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr));
serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

ret = connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
if(ret < 0){
    printf("[-]Error in connection.\n");
    exit(1);
}
printf("[+]Connected to Server.\n");

for(uint64_t i = 0; i < torrent.block_count; i++){
    printf("Client: \t");
    scanf("%s", &buffer[0]);
    send(clientSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);

    if(strcmp(buffer, ":exit") == 0){
        close(clientSocket);
        printf("[-]Disconnected from server.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(recv(clientSocket, buffer, 1024, 0) < 0){
        printf("[-]Error in receiving data.\n");
    }else{
        printf("Server: \t%s\n", buffer);
    }
}
```

//Some people have had problem in client loop try adding this which is just a confitmation  to see if blocks are counted properly

```
            uint64_t block_counter = 0;
            counter_congf = true;
            while (block_counter < torrent.block_count && ct == true) {

                if (torrent.block_map[block_counter] != true) 
                    counter_congf = false;  

                else block_counter ++;                      
            }               

        }
        close(client_sockfd);
```

return 0;
}